# Prove this monotone sequence has a bound, thus it converges.

Tags: analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $r>0$ and $\frac{r^n}{n!}$ Prove that it converges.  I know that it is eventually decreasing, so it is monotone.  How do I get a bound for it to show that it converges?

Also how would I go about showing $\lim_{n\to inf} \frac{r^n}{n!}=0 $.

Would I just use the definition to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every term is the same as the previous, times $r/n$. For $n$ large enough, this ratio is less than one, so that the terms go decreasing to zero.